# Will coated chicken fry up ok if not fried right away?

Tags: frying, kitchen-safety

Will coated chicken fry up okay after keeping in the frig for an hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you coating it? Is it coated in eggs and then flour? If so, then yes. That's exactly how I make mine. The egg ends up sticking better if you do that. I learned this from [Alton Brown's cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158479559X), and use the method all the time.